# Trying to stepwise iterate through 2 files in python

Tags: python, loops, readlines

I am trying to merge two LARGE input files together into 1 output, sorting as I go.

```
## Above I counted the number of lines in each table

print("Processing Table Lines: table 1 has " + str(count1) + " and table 2 has " + str(count2) )
newLine, compare, line1, line2 = [], 0, [], []

while count1 + count2 > 0:
    if count1 > 0 and compare <= 0: count1, line1 = count1 - 1, ifh1.readline().rstrip().split('\t')
    else: line1 = []
    if count2 > 0 and compare >= 0: count2, line2 = count2 - 1, ifh2.readline().rstrip().split('\t')
    else: line2 = []

    compare = compareTableLines( line1, line2 )
    newLine = mergeLines( line1, line2, compare, tIndexes )

    ofh.write('\t'.join( newLine + '\n'))
```

What I expect to happen is that as lines are written to output, I pull the next line in the file I used to be read in if available.  I also expect that the loop cuts out once both files are empty.

However I keep getting this error:
    ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data

I just don't see how to get around it.  Either file is too large to keep in memory so I want to read as I go.

Comment: Are the two input files sorted? Can you show us some examples? And what does `compareTableLines()` do?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of merging two ordered files, CSV files in this case, using [`heapq.merge()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) and [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). Given 2 CSV files:

**`x.csv`**:

```
key1,99
key2,100
key4,234
```

**`y.csv`**:

```
key1,345
key2,4
key3,45
```

Running:

```py
import csv, heapq, itertools

keyfun = lambda row: row[0]

with open("x.csv") as inf1, open("y.csv") as inf2, open("z.csv", "w") as outf:
    in1, in2, out = csv.reader(inf1), csv.reader(inf2), csv.writer(outf)
    for key, rows in itertools.groupby(heapq.merge(in1, in2, key=keyfun), keyfun):
        out.writerow([key, sum(int(r[1]) for r in rows)])
```

we get:

**`z.csv`**:

```
key1,444
key2,104
key3,45
key4,234
```